# I have a styled td class that makes my comment button look like a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After text is entered in the textarea i would like to target this class to let the user submit by pressing enter.

```
cmnt += '<td class="cmnt_save" data-id="' + id + '">Save Comment</td>';
```

[image: I would like to Target the Save comment td class using jquery]

Everything I've tried has failed miserably.. i've tried using jquery, JS and some inline JS too.

Here's my function with my tables:

```
// This function retrieves comments
function get_comments(id ,afterCtl ,ctl) {
    var cmnt = '';

show_loading('.loading_box');

// Create the new row in the database - ajax returns json version.
var add_url = '/ajax/project_comment_list.php?id=' + id;

var slot = $.getJSON(add_url)
    .done(function(data) {
        // Draw the entire comment-block then display it

        cmnt = '<tr class="cmnts">';
        cmnt += '    <td colspan="11">';
        cmnt += '        <table>';
        cmnt += '            <tr class="cmnt_add">';
        cmnt += '                <td class="cmnt_text">'
        cmnt += '                    <input type="text" id="cmnt_new" name="cmnt_new" rows="1">';
        //cmnt += '                    <textarea id="cmnt_new" name="cmnt_new" rows="1"></textarea>';
        cmnt += '                </td>';
        cmnt += '                <td></td>';
        cmnt += '                <td></td>';
        cmnt += '                <td class="cmnt_save" data-id="' + id + '">Save Comment</td>';
        cmnt += '            </tr>';

        $.each(data.ProjectComments, function (index, value) {
            cmnt += add_comment_row(value.TEXT ,blank_if_undefined(value.EMP_INIT) ,value.ENTER_DATE);
        });

        cmnt += '        </table>';
        cmnt += '    </td>';
        cmnt += '</tr>';

        remove_comments(ctl);

        $(afterCtl).after(cmnt);
        $('#cmnt_new').focus();

        $(ctl).addClass('cmnt_active');
        $(ctl).html('&nbsp;-&nbsp;');

        //register the event
        $('td.cmnt_save').click(function(){
            add_comment($(this));
        });

        comment_shown = id;
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) {
        hide_loading('.loading_box');
        show_error('There was an error pulling the comments.');
    });

    //wire up the event
    $('textarea#cmnt_new').keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Cripes!  You pressed enter!');
        }
    })
```

}

If anyone could be of any help to get this task accomplished or just recommend other/better ways of making this function correctly. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `function add_comment(ctl) {
    //todo: remove carriage returns
    //todo: recognize carriage return as clicking the "Save Comment" faux-button
    var cmnt = '';

    show_loading('.loading_box');

    // Create the new row in the database - ajax returns json version.
    var add_url = '/ajax/project_comment_new.php';
    add_url += '?id=' + ctl.attr('data-id');
    add_url += '&text=' + $('#cmnt_new').val();
    add_url += '&emp_init=' + $('#emp_init').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you just want to save the comment the user added after the user hits the enter key in the relative text-area.

I think you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5JKy8/2/

HTML

```
<table id="comments">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td><textarea class="comment" rows="1" id="333"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td><textarea class="comment" rows="1" id="666"></textarea></td>
    </tr>                
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("body").on("keydown",".comment", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {            
            var comment = $(this).val(),
                id = $(this).data("id");

            saveComment(comment,id).done( function() {
                $(this).parent("td").text(comment);
            });
        }
    });    

});

function saveComment(comment,id) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'yourScript.php',
        data: {comment:comment,id:id}
    });
}
```

Note: In the jsfiddle the saveComment() is returning a boolean for demo purposes, but just use the commented out code.

Answer (score 1):

What's the ID of the text field..?  `#cmnt_new`?

```
$('#static-parent').on('keyup', '#cmnt_new', function(ev){ 
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        // do whatever here
    }
});
```

Where `#static-parent` is something that is not dynamically loaded and `#cmnt_new` is inside of it (a parent).  I believe you could even do `$(document).on(..`.  For scripts to work on dynamically loaded content, you have to use a delegate and go through something static on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Event Object's `keyCode` property `onkeyup`. `event.keyCode === 13` for the enter button, like:

```
$('#cmnt_new').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    // do your thing here
  }
});
```

Note, that you've combined `<input type='text' />` closing it with `</textarea>`.

Comment: I've tried something like this and i couldn't even get it to alert.  `$('.cmnt_new').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
        alert("send ajax");
    }
});`

Comment: Is it a `textarea`? I don't think so. Also, `.cmnt_new` would be a `className` not an id, which you would use the `#` symbol for. Get rid of the closing `textarea` tag.

Comment: fixed, but still nothing.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.. still nothing though.

Comment: What is supposed to work? `add_comment()`? Inside that function you have `$('this')` which would refer to the element itself, not `$('#cmnt_new')`. `$('textarea#cmnt_new')` is still invalid code. Additionally, you should declare your variables with the keyword `var`, otherwise they're global.